# IE bug with hover on select and options

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dojo, hover

I'm trying to make a hover on a div but when I hover a option the hover of div is affected.

Example code:

```
<div class="levelThreeMenuColumnTwo" id="clientFormMenu">
    <div class="formMenuPFS">
        <select name="select1">
            <option value="TN">
                Tennessee
            </option>
            <option value="VA" selected="selected">
                Virginia
            </option>
            <option value="WA">
                Washington
            </option>
            <option value="FL">
                Florida
            </option>
            <option value="CA">
                California
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>
<style>
.formMenuPFS{
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
    width:110px;
    height:110px;
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
}
.levelThreeMenuColumnTwo:hover .formMenuPFS{
    display:block;
}
.levelThreeMenuColumnTwo{
    display:block;
    background-color:green;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
</style>
```

Woking in FF but not in IE.

Correct behaviour:
 When hover green div show red div.
 When hover select or option keep showing red div.

If javascript is needed I can use dojo 1.4.
Thank you.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Can you show what you have so far (the above code) on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), making sure that it still works in Firefox and still breaks in IE?

Comment: All IE versions. http://jsbin.com/aralak. The code is only the above code, you can copy and past into html document and test.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old problem but I had the same problem I fixed it the following way in your jsbin. Instead of using the CSS :hover I used the jQuery hover and add an `event.stopPropagation()` too the select.

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".levelThreeMenuColumnTwo").hover(function() {
        $('.formMenuPFS').show();
        $('.formMenuPFS select').mouseleave(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
    }, function() {
        $('.formMenuPFS').hide();
        $('.formMenuPFS select').mouseleave(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
    });
});
```

jsbin
http://jsbin.com/xitafazoca/

Comment: your adding event handlers in your event handler that's probably not what you want

Comment: Well since you want too cancel the event of mouseLeave when your hovering that specific div. I think thats what you want in this situation.

Comment: but the `mouseleave` event with `stopPropogation` only needs to be attached once and then it will always intercept mouseleave. It doesn't need to be re-attached every time that `levelThreeMenuColumnTwo` gets hovered on

Comment: Ahh I see, can you create an example on how you would only attach it once in  this example?

I cant think of a way myself atm that would